# How to write PHP cron jobs without cPanel?

Tags: php, cron

I know we have cron jobs in PHP. but I have a project in development phase and we won't have cPanel access.

We have a PHP + MSSQL application that needs to check the database periodically every 1 minute and collect the data and send a mail to a store admininstrator.

How can we do this?

Comment: there are no cronjobs in php. a cronjob is a function of the OS. if you have access just set it from the command line `crontab -e` cpanel is common on shared hosts ( for people with limited skills) , but not on much elese

Comment: What OS are you using for dev?

Comment: We are using Windows 2008 / WAMP Environment PHP / MYSQL / MSSQL

Comment: no cronjobs in windows, but there is task scheduler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a alternative of cron jobs solution by implement you function in a file (eg: /very/secret.php if your jobs need to be secure, make sure the function can be call only when it get the right parameter eg: /very/secret.php?key=long-random).

Then use some free cron job server on the web like: https://www.easycron.com/ or https://www.setcronjob.com/ (just do a web search for "free online cron jobs"). You give them your URL and some configuration and then your jobs will be executed by them at a specific time of day.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you need to run a script to check the database periodically every one minute and collect the data and send a mail to store admin. Also I understand that you have a script and you need to run that script every one minute.

It can be done using "cron job", if you are using Linux server. Or if you are using Windows, there is a way to schedule the task (to run that script every min).

Note: it is nothing to with cPanel. Actually, the cPanel provides a user friendly GUI to schedule the cron job.

But if you are not using panel, you can do it manually.

If you are using Linux, here you can see, how to add the cron job - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

If you are using Windows, here you can see, how to add the cron job - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i need a solution to invoke cron job kind of thing in my php code itself. correct me if i m wrong :)

Comment: I don't think you can do that in your php code itself. And also It is not a good practice to do in your php code.